# Convergence of expectation of product from truncation

Tags: probability-theory

Say $X$ and $Y$ are two random variables such that $(\mathbb{E}X)^2<\mathbb{E}X^2<\infty$ and $(\mathbb{E}Y)^2<\mathbb{E}Y^2<\infty.$

I want to argue that as $M\to\infty,$

(i) $\mathbb{E}X1_{|X|\leq M}\rightarrow \mathbb{E}X$

(ii) $\mathbb{E}X^21_{|X|\leq M}\rightarrow \mathbb{E}X^2$

(iii) $\mathbb{E}XY1_{|X|\leq M, |Y|\leq M}\rightarrow \mathbb{E}XY$

(i) follows from the monotone convergence theorem by observing that $\max\{X,0\}$ and $\min\{X,0\}$ have finite expectations. (ii) is simply the monotone convergence theorem.

Can we say (iii) is true based on the assumptions I made?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It follows from the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality that $X \cdot Y \in L^1$. Therefore, (iii) is a direct consequence of the dominated convergence theorem.